# General equation in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In my notes, the following is written:
The most general equation of a line in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is $ax+by=c,$
 Where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b$ not both $=0.$

I understand this, is it just something trivial, and a simple demonstration of a linear equation?

My question(s) is/are:

Are all linear equations in $\mathbb{R^2}$ simply straight lines, and linear equations in $\mathbb{R^3}$ represent planes?

And suppose, in the example above, $a=b=0$. Would $c=0$ represent a point in the one dimensional plane?

Just an idea, probably wrong $\ddot\smile.$

Comment: You mean "the general equation for a line", not "the most general equation".

Comment: @quasi my lecturer wrote 'the' most general equation...', but I would understand it as the standard/general equation of a line?

Comment: For your other question, recall that for an equation with at most two vaiables $x,y$, the graph of the equation, by _definition_, is the set of all points $(x,y)$ which satisfy the equation. Hence if $a = b = c = 0$, the graph is ...? And if $a=b=0$ but $c \ne 0$, the graph is ...?

Comment: Well, if you consider a system of equations it gets more general, and that would allow you to transform the space so to speak. But perhaps this is the only simple equation. Does that help?

Comment: @Gurjinder: I'm sure your lecturer _intended_ to say "the most general equation for a _line_ in the $xy$-plane". Lecturers are sometimes not careful about the written wording (but may have said it correctly out loud).

Comment: It's not *entirely* trivial IMO. At least in the US, I think most people are brought up with the "lines look like $y = mx + b$" kind of mentality, which works for all non-vertical lines (hence your form is *more* general, and does indeed encompass all lines).

Comment: @pjs36: But according to Gurjinder, the lecturer's statement made no mention of the word "line". Of course, if the context of the lecture was "equations for a line", then the missing word "line" could be regarded as there by default.

Comment: @quasi yeah, sorry, should have made the topic clear.

Comment: @quasi for $a=b=c=0$, there would be no graph, and for $c \neq 0 $ and $a=b=0$, this too would present no graph? So would this mean that there is no geometrical interpretation?

Comment: @Gurijinder: I see you edited in the word "line". Then there's no problem.

Comment: @theREALyumdub mmm, not really, sorry, I'm quite new to the introduction of mathematical rigour and goemetric intuitions. What would you mean by 'transforming the space's?

Comment: @Gurjinder: No, not quite. For $a=b=c=0$, the equation is $0=0$ which is satisfied by _all_ points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so the graph is the whole plane (all of $\mathbb{R}^2$). For the case $a=b=0$, but $c \ne 0$, the equation is $0=c$ which is not satisfied by any point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so the graph is the empty set.

Comment: @quasi ohh, so for the equation $z=1$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, this would be a plane parallel to the $xy-plane$ as for $ax+by+cz=d,$ $a=b=c=0$ and $c=d=1$, and all points $(x,y)$ satisfy this equation?

Comment: @Gurjinder: As to your main question, pjs36's comment addresses the issue of why the form $ax + by = c$ with $a,b$ not both $0$ is called "general form". All lines in the $xy$-plane have equations which can be expressed in that form, and conversely, for any equation of that form, the graph in the $xy$-plane is a straight line.

Comment: @quasi  okay, cool, thanks.

Comment: You need to know what space you're in. The equation $z=1$, by default, would be regarded as an equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: On the other hand, take the equation $x=1$. If the space is specified as $\mathbb{R}$, the graph of the equation $x=1$ is a point. If the space is specified as $\mathbb{R}^2$, the graph of the equation $x=1$ is a line. If the space is specified as $\mathbb{R}^3$, the graph of the equation $x=1$ is a plane.

Comment: @Gurjinder: To slightly correct the wording of one of your previous comments, if the space is specified as $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or assumed so by default), the graph of the equation $z=1$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, parallel to the $xy$-plane, with equation $ax+by+cz=d$, where $a=b=0$ and $c=d=1$. Explicitly, the graph is the set of points of the form $(x,y,1)$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,  but $x,y$ are otherwise unrestricted.

Comment: @quasi cool, got it, thanks. $\ddot \smile$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I realized after posting that you might not know what the scalar product is yet. In this case I suggest you stop at the "Yes" in the first two answers below, because the answers rely heavily on the intuition provided by the scalar product. If you don't know what that is, the answers are probably more confusing than helpful. **However** I do suggest that either way you take a look at the third answer ("Nope"), because that one only requires stuff you definitely know.

**Are all linear equations in $\mathbb R^2$ simply straight lines?** Yes, in the sense that you specified above (nonzero $a$ and $b$). The reason is this: The equation can be rewritten (in my opinion more intuitively) as
$$
ax+by=c \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \Biggl\langle\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} \Bigg|  \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} \Biggr\rangle = c
$$
where $\langle \boldsymbol u| \boldsymbol v\rangle$ is the scalar product $\boldsymbol u^\top \boldsymbol v$. The right equation should always evoke the intuition of the variable point $[x,y]^\top$ being projected onto the constant reference $[a,b]^\top$. That is the key feature of the scalar product. If $\|[a,b]^\top\|=1$, then $c$ is exactly the length of that part in $[x,y]^\top$ that is parallel to $[a,b]^\top$. If $\|[a,b]\| = A \neq 1$, then $c/A$ is the parallel length.

Either way, the scalar product expression essentially says: *"I hold for all points $[x,y]$ that have a constant parallel part with $[a,b]$."* If you draw it on a piece of paper, that means that $[a,b]^\top$ is perpendicular to the line of all possible $[x,y]^\top$, which intersects $[a,b]^\top$ at a distance of $c/A$ (from the origin $[0,0]^\top$).

**Do all linear equations  linear equations in $\mathbb R^3$ represent planes?** Yes, in the same sense as above. Consider:
$$
ax+by+cz=d \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \Biggl\langle\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} \Biggl|  \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} \Biggr\rangle = d
$$
which holds for all points $[x,y,z]^\top$ that have with $[a,b,c]^\top$ a parallel part of $d/\|[a,b,c]^\top\|$, and an arbitrary perpendicular part. Again, $[a,b,c]$ specifies the normal direction, and the "arbitrary perpendicular part" has two degrees of freedom, meaning: All points on a plane that is offset by $d/\|[a,b,c]^\top\|$ in direction $[a,b,c]^\top$.

**In the example above, $a=b=0$. Would $c=0$ represent a point in the one dimensional plane?** Nope, but we don't even need geometric intuitions for this one. Just look at the resulting equation:
$$
0\cdot x + 0 \cdot y = 0
$$
For which choice of $x$ and $y$ is it satisfied? The answer will give you the set of $[x,y]^\top$ that this equation defines. Do they all lie on the same line? Or does this particular equation provide a different set of $[x,y]^\top$ points altogether?

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I have found this very helpful, and will look into the scalar product.